# Existence of isomorphism from the complex vector bundle to the dual

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I know for a complex vector bundle $E\to X$, we have Chern class $c_i(E)=(-1)^ic_i(E^*)$. Therefore, in many cases, $E\to X$ and $E^*\to X$ are not isomorphic.

I wonder if there exists some non-trivial complex vector bundle $E\to X$ s.t. $c_i(E)=0$ when $i$ is odd? Moreover under this condition, if there exists some non-trivial complex vector bundle $E\to X$ s.t., $E\to X$ and $E^*\to X$ are isomorphic?

Comment: Sure.  Let $V$ be any vector bundle on $X$, and consider $E=V\oplus V^*$.  The isomorphism $E\cong E^*$ is the obvious one.

Comment: @user10354138 are there other examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195592/21564), there is a bijection between isomorphism classes of principal $SU(2)$-bundles over a four-dimensional manifold $X$ (or even CW complex) and $H^4(X; \mathbb{Z})$ given by $P \mapsto c_2(P)$.

So over any four-manifold $X$, and any choice of $c \in H^4(X; \mathbb{Z})$, there is a rank two complex vector bundle $E$ with $c_1(E) = 0$ and $c_2(E) = c$. Note that $c_1(E^*) = -c_1(E) = 0$ and $c_2(E^*) = c_2(E) = c$, so $E^* \cong E$. If $c \neq 0$, then $E\cong E^*$ is not trivial

Comment: Does a principal $SU(2)$ bundle mean the bundle is of ranks 2 and first chern class vanishes?

Comment: A principal $SU(2)$-bundle is something slightly different, but it is equivalent (via the associated bundle construction) to a complex vector bundle of rank two with vanishing first Chern class.